# Union Struct C# - Equivalent Or Equals?

Tags: c#, c++, unions

see struct below

```
struct STRUCT_ITEM
{

short Index;

    union
    {
        short Value;

        struct
        {
            unsigned char Type;
            unsigned char Values;
        };

    } Effect[3];
};
```

Hello .. Good evening. I would like if it is possible to convert a structure in **C ++** to **C #**?
I would like the new structure to contain the array of 3 objects, as you can see in the code in **C ++**.

Is to be used like this:

```
var Item = new Item ();

Item.Effect [2] .Type = 2;
```

I just get it that way:

```
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public short Index;

    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public short MountHP;

    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public byte EF1;

    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public byte EFV1;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public byte EF2;

    [FieldOffset(5)]
    public byte EFV2;

    [FieldOffset(6)]
    public byte EF3;

    [FieldOffset(7)]
    public byte EFV3;
```

---

Is it possible to contain array in the structure? This structure contains the maximum size of 8 bytes.

Who can help, I am grateful! Thank you so much

Comment: Please [edit] to make an effort to fix your formatting. Do not use tab characters; use spaces for indentation. While you're making that [edit], add a tag for the language you're asking about, instead of putting it in the title. The tag system works extremely well here and doesn't need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.
and Yes, The array can use in Sturcture.

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct STRUCT_SUB_ITEM
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public short Value;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public byte Type;
        [FieldOffset(1)]
        public byte Values;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct STRUCT_ITEM
    {
        short index;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
        public STRUCT_SUB_ITEM[] Effect;
    }
```

and Test just like this.

```
    static void test3()
    {
        STRUCT_ITEM item = new STRUCT_ITEM();
        item.Effect = new STRUCT_SUB_ITEM[3];

        item.Effect[0].Type = 1;
        item.Effect[0].Values = 2;

        item.Effect[1].Type = 1;
        item.Effect[1].Values = 2;

        item.Effect[2].Type = 1;
        item.Effect[2].Values = 2;

        Console.WriteLine(item.Effect[2].Value);
    }
```

And an Array with restrict types (bool, int, double, ... ) Using Fixed keyword,  it dosen't need alloc memory.

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public unsafe struct STRUCT_ITEM2
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public fixed byte item_01[260];
    }
```

Comment: You have roughly the right approach, lifting the union out of the declaration is the key.  You did however forget about the Index field and none of this requires `unsafe`.

Comment: I'm currently learnning for this. Thanks for  a good point. But the last section of source,  fixed field needed unsafe keywords anyway.

Comment: Next time, I expect something other than a good point with your beautiful source code.

Comment: Thanks so much, my friend. This is correct solution! grateful.

Comment: It’s good to help you. If it is helpful for you  accept this as answer. thanks.